# Implement Stack using Java

Tags: java, stack

I try to implement stack structure on Java and I have some problems on the pop method. Before pop, i want to check wether the stack is empty. 
The return says The local variable item may not have been initialized. When I remove if(!is.empty), it has no error.
could someone tell me why?
Thanks a lot.

```
public class ArrayStack {
private String[] s;
private int N=0;

    public ArrayStack(){
    s=new String[1];   //initialize the array;
}

private void reSize(int capacity){
    String[] copy=new String[capacity];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        copy[i]=s[i];
    }
    s=copy;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return N==0;
}

public int stackSize(){
    return N;
}

public void push(String item){
    if(item!=null){
        if(N==s.length){
            reSize(s.length*2);
        }
    }
        s[N++]=item;
}

public String pop(){
    String item;
    if(isEmpty()){
        item=s[--N];
        s[N]=null;
    }
    if(N>0&&N==s.length/4){
        reSize(s.length/4);
    }
    return item;
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend giving the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) a read. We like questions with a small, reproducible example. Read more at http://sscce.org/.

Comment: I think `if(isEmpty())` in your post should be `if (!isEmpty())`, based on your comments.  Assuming that's true: if `isEmpty()` is true then what do you **want** your `pop()` to return?  Or do you want it to do something else, like throw an exception?

Comment: Do not use a single letter variable name for an instance variable. Do not use a capitalized name for an instance variable. Why do you test for null in push() but then blindly add the item, even if it is null, even if it will not fit on the stack?

Comment: Oh I made the mistake. If !isEmpty is true. pop will return one item out of the stack

Comment: Also, use `System.arrayCopy()` to copy the values to the resized array rather than doing it yourself with a for loop. The former is likely to use a faster native implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1, if you want to throws an exception when the stack is empty:

```
public String pop() {
    String item = s[--n];
    s[n] = null;
    if (n == (s.length / SHRINK_FACTOR)) {
        reSize(s.length / SHRINK_FACTOR);
    }
    return item;
}
```

Option 2, if you want to return `null` when the stack is empty:

```
public String pop() {
    String item = null;
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        item = s[--n];
        s[n] = null;
    }
    if (n == (s.length / SHRINK_FACTOR)) {
        reSize(s.length / SHRINK_FACTOR);
    }
    return item;
}
```

Some further notes:

- before a variable can be used it must be given an initial value. Therefor if your condition is not met and `item` is returned without first giving it a value, the compiler will throw an error.
- by convention, class attributes start with a small letter
- instead of using magic numbers (`4`), introduce some constants in your class:

  ```
  private static final int SHRINK_FACTOR = 4;
  ```
- consider writing unit tests to describe and ensure the expected behaviour:

ArrayStackTest.java:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.annotations.Ignore;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ArrayStackTest {

    @Test
    public void testPushAndPop() {
        final ArrayStack stack = new ArrayStack();
        assertTrue(stack.isEmpty());
        stack.push("A");
        assertFalse(stack.isEmpty());
        stack.push("B");
        stack.push("C");
        assertEquals("C", stack.pop());
        assertEquals("B", stack.pop());
        assertEquals("A", stack.pop());
    }

    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void testException() {
        final ArrayStack stack = new ArrayStack();
        stack.pop();
    }

    // remove @Ignore for option 2
    @Ignore
    @Test
    public void testPopReturnNull() {
        final ArrayStack stack = new ArrayStack();
        assertNull(stack.pop());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialize your local variable item

```
String item;
```

Change it to

```
String item = ""; or String item = NULL;
```

should resolve the issue

Comment: i.e. `if (!isEmpty()) //assuming you corrected your isEmpty() to !isEmpty()` so if the list is empty, you will return an uninitialized variable item

Comment: This will resolve the compile-time error, but it won't "resolve" the issue until the questioner decides how he wants `pop()` to behave for an empty stack.  "Quick fixes" like this (just get it to compile or to run without thinking about design issues) are how bugs creep into code.

Comment: Sorry everyone, if the stack is empty, I will add one line that shows the stack is empty. After I add it, it works well.

Comment: Thanks all of your help. Now I understand the mistake